# How to show face in edit mode after hiding with "H"

Tags: modeling, interface, workflow

Very simple question but I couldn't find answer

I'm modeling some complex stuff which I need to hide some faces to move forward, but after I'm done I want to display those faces back

Answer (score 9, accepted):

<kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> or *3D view > Header > Mesh > Show/Hide >Show Hidden* will do it:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I'm fairly sure that it is <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>h</kbd>

Comment: Just Alt+H. (In 2.81) -- Thanks.